# Electron and CSS - Two divs with the same FIXED height are displayed differently?

Tags: css, height, electron

I'm creating an **[Electron](https://electron.atom.io/)** app where I have two rows of buttons contained in two divs. The divs' colours are darker than their buttons' colours, and there is a very small **2px** gap between the buttons and their divs. The first div, which has the exact same height, the exact same buttons and is only slightly less wide than the second, has a noticeable **3px** gap between it and its buttons vertically. I understand than a pixel in **CSS** isn't the same as a pixel on the screen, but I was under the impression that a "**CSS Pixel**" would stay the same throughout the application. The divs are in a class with these properties:

```
background-color: #14191E;
height: 22px;
right: 15px;
```

The buttons inside them are also supposed to be **18px** high, but this value also differs when displayed, regarless of the fact that they are in the same class with the same rules. I have attached a screenshot to show what I mean.

**i.imgur.com/kF53NSJ.png**

As you can see, "**x**," which is exactly the same both times where it is drawn, is one pixel bigger than the bottom div, but the same height as the first div. Also, there is **3px** between the top div and the button(s), but there is only **2px** between the bottom div and its buttons (*but I want **2px** in both cases*).

**Solution** (**?**)

I don't know if this counts as a solution or more of a workaround, but it seems the browsers have a particular problem with **22px**? I used [this](https://hastebin.com/aruduyihux.xml) html to reproduce the error, and the same problem occured, except when I change the height property to 20px, the error is resolved and both divs are equal. This is shown here: **i.imgur.com/hEzDxoG.png** (*I need ten reputation for images and more than two links*).

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Is it specifically an electron issue? Looking good in plain html and desktop browser?

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/PjHrrOy.png) is taken from the **Chrome** browser, but it should be noted that both **Chrome** and **Electron** think that both divs are **22px** high in "inspect element" mode.